# Body effect on NMOS4 LTSpice simulation

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, simulation, nmos

I am trying to observe the effect of a negative voltage on the NMOS4 model in LTSpice. I have a DC sim running and a step parameter for the voltage. However the current curve (and threshold voltage) does not change. I have included a picture with the current and body voltage, and the ASC code. I have also tried including K1 and PHI parameters but the threshold voltage still doesn't change.
[image: Body effect test bench]

Here is the ASC file.

```
SHEET 1 1880 756
WIRE 1184 -192 960 -192
WIRE 1184 -112 1184 -192
WIRE 960 -96 960 -192
WIRE 1088 -48 960 -48
WIRE 912 -16 784 -16
WIRE 1088 -16 1088 -48
WIRE 784 32 784 -16
WIRE 1088 96 1088 64
WIRE 1088 96 1056 96
WIRE 784 128 784 112
WIRE 960 128 960 0
WIRE 960 128 784 128
WIRE 1056 128 1056 96
WIRE 1056 128 960 128
WIRE 1184 128 1184 -32
WIRE 1184 128 1056 128
WIRE 1056 176 1056 128
WIRE 1152 368 928 368
WIRE 1152 448 1152 368
WIRE 928 464 928 368
WIRE 1056 512 928 512
WIRE 880 544 752 544
WIRE 752 592 752 544
WIRE 1056 656 1056 512
WIRE 1056 656 1024 656
WIRE 752 688 752 672
WIRE 928 688 928 560
WIRE 928 688 752 688
WIRE 1024 688 1024 656
WIRE 1024 688 928 688
WIRE 1152 688 1152 528
WIRE 1152 688 1024 688
WIRE 1024 736 1024 688
FLAG 1056 176 0
FLAG 1024 736 0
SYMBOL nmos4 912 -96 R0
WINDOW 3 56 60 Left 2
WINDOW 123 56 88 Left 2
SYMATTR Value testn
SYMATTR Value2 l=0.25 w=0.375 ad=0.3u as=0.3u pd=1.875u ps=1.875u
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMBOL voltage 784 16 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 2
SYMBOL voltage 1184 -128 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 2
SYMBOL voltage 752 576 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value ""
SYMBOL voltage 1152 432 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMATTR Value -2.4
SYMBOL pmos4 880 464 R0
WINDOW 3 56 60 Left 2
WINDOW 123 56 88 Left 2
SYMATTR Value testp
SYMATTR Value2 l=0.25 w=1.125 ad=0.7u as=0.7u pd=2.375u ps=2.375u
SYMATTR InstName M2
SYMBOL voltage 1088 -32 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V5
SYMATTR Value {V5}
TEXT -56 -32 Left 2 !.MODEL testn NMOS (kp=115u vt0=0.7 lambda=0.01)
TEXT 912 -312 Left 2 !.dc V1 0 2.4 10m
TEXT -72 616 Left 2 !.MODEL testp PMOS (kp=30u vt0=-0.7 lambda=0.01)
TEXT 1496 424 Left 2 !;dc V4  -2.4 0 10m V3 -2.4 0 0.4
TEXT 1464 -152 Left 2 !.step param V5  -5 0 1
```

Comment: Your length (`L`) and width (`W`) are in the range of meters (`0.25` and `0.375`, respectively. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: You need to set the `gamma` parameter to a nonzero value.  Otherwise `Vth` reduces down to exactly `Vto` when using the LEVEL1 model (the default level which you are using).